# Flutter columns and rows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it just me, but who else thinks that Flutters columns and rows are the wrong way around?

Surely rows should run from top to bottom and columns across.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology of the word row is horizontal. A column is always vertical. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_(database)

[Row class:](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html)

> A widget that displays its children in a horizontal array.

[Column class:](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

> A widget that displays its children in a vertical array.

Every direct widget under a row is horizontal while when you put it in a container or another widget every widget under that tree is getting the alignment from the next one above.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But in flutter its seems to be the other way around. Take a look at the following link - 
https://flutter.io/widgets/layout/#Multi-child%20layout%20widgets

Comment: @Jakes Yes. Vertical means from top to bottom; Horizontal from left to right.

Comment: Not sure if I am completly getting what you mean. But basically every direct element under a row is horizontal while when you put in a container or another widget every widget under it is getting the alignment from the next one above.

Comment: I get it now. What threw me, was the adding of the children and the name of the outer widget, i.e. row and column

Comment: When you add a row to a DB table, would you expect it to find it added horizontally or vertically?

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever used SQL, and have looked at its tables,(Or any other table) you can clearly observe that all the columns are arranged vertically while all the rows are arranged horizontally. 
The same principle is followed in flutter.